# SWF Maximum workflow execution time limitation

Tags: java, ruby, workflow, flash

Amazon SWF has a limit of **Maximum workflow execution time** of one year.
Here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-limits.html

In case of workflows which need human approval it might take more than a year to complete a workflow. I tried to use different methods to find a workaround for this limitation but could find any solution for that. I was wondering if anyone have some experience on this or have any recommendation.

Thanks

Comment: This probably needs to be asked at Amazon's tech help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating a lot about this issue seems there is only possible solution for that is the one which is provided in Amazon recipes itself, which is `continue-as-new` workflow and carrying over state of workflow to new execution.

This workaround might not be easy to deploy for more complex workflows.

Here is SWF Ruby sample:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-flow-ruby-samples/tree/master/samples/periodic